# installing node on centos 6.0

Tags: linux, installation, centos-6, node.js

while googling on how to install node on my centos box, I found this link : https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager.

This page suggests that I do the following.
"RHEL/CentOS/Scientific Linux 6

Node.js and npm are available from the Fedora Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository. If you haven't already done so, first enable(https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) EPEL and then run the following command to install node and npm:"

I don't know how to enable it -- can someone step me through the steps ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

Source: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Node and manage specific versions, I'd suggest [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)